# Laravel Passport with ReactJS Users Sessions

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, session-cookies, laravel-passport

The context:

I have an application with in Front-end: ReactJS to user's interactions and Laravel in Back-end: to manage user's data.

I'm trying to manage user's session expiration with Passport Laravel in Back-end.

What i have done:

At each login on Front-end, Passport Laravel send an oauth_access_token and expiration (set to 10 minutes) in the response. In the WebApp, I store the access_token and expiration in sessionStorage and set them into a cookie to manage user's session. Every action user makes in the WebApp, i refresh the cookie to avoid expiration session in Front. But if the user is really inactive i redirect him to the login page.

Also, I would like to protect some private routes in the API backend which require authentication via middleware.

I have done this, but even if user is active in Front, in the table oauth_access_token, the token expiration of the user hasn't been updated. So the user could not access to protect routes because his token is correct but has expired.

So i'm wondering, how could i keep the same token for the time of his session for the user and update it every time he is interact with the API Laravel ? And refreshing the same token with 10 minutes more for example.

I'm searching for the good practice to implement in the middleware, any ideas ?

Sorry for my English which is not perfect.

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

Initially I was using laravel passport to authenticate my users, which worked really fine by the way, but I had trouble trying to maintain the user's session on a cookie. I had it set it to about half an hour, problem was even if I was still logged in and using the system, it would still sign me out automatically since the cookie expiry time didn't update and it became hectic since I didn't want to keep on sending data to the server to update the cookie contents. I know that is stupid cause it's the only way to maintain the session, but I needed a more secure way of doing this.

So I migrated to sanctum. At first I was skeptical on it but as I read on it's uses I saw it as better option for front end authentication and session management since it uses laravel's cookies out-of-the-box and there's also a package for maintaining the session.

Check it out:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sanctum